# objective-c refactor method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have the following code:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
...

}
```

As you can see it passes in a UITextField. I also have this code duplicated in the same ViewController but passing in a UITextView.

I want to be able to refactor this into a single method which passes in either the UITextField or UITextView? How can I do this?

Also this code appears in other View Controllers, so ideally I'd like to place it in a helper class, very new to iOS so not sure where to go from here.

I've removed most of the code from the method for brevity, but what it does is it slides the UI controls into view when the iOS keyboard appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expect UIView, as it seems you don't use any special text properties from those views.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UIView *)textField
{
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call a helper methods, that expects a UIView, the common super class.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return [self textBeginEditing:textField];
}


-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    return [self textBeginEditing:textView];
}


-(void)textBeginEditing:(UIView *)view
{
     //and if you need to do something, where you need to now, if it is a textView or a field, use

    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
        //…
    } else if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]){
        //…
    }
}
```